# How to load AMD modules in dojo2 app

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there any way to load AMD modules into an app generated using the new dojo 2 cli (`@dojo/cli`)? And have them be included in the webpack built output (`@dojo/cli-build-webpack`)?

I can see `@dojo/loader` in `node_modules` but I'm not sure how to take advantage of it. If I just include it via script tag in `index.html`, I'm guessing that the AMD modules won't be built into the webpack output.

My use case is that I'd like to build an app using ESRI's JavaScript API (https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-js-api/tree/4master) which is build on dojo 1.12.1 and uses AMD format for their modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are working on it: [github.com/dojo/cli-build/issues/165](http://github.com/dojo/cli-build/issues/165)